# Multi-Parent linking

Tags: algorithm, graph

Where I can find the display algorithm for multi-parents linking.
I like to draw it on 2-dimension paper without crossing lines.

So it is connecting with Set of parents to set of children where there is many  to many relationship.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph#Kuratowski.27s_and_Wagner.27s_theorems) and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planarity_testing) before looking further. Planarity is a tricky animal and in many real world applications is simply not doable.

Answer (score 1):

The layout engines in [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) attempt to solve this problem in various ways, though I think they will all allow lines to cross if the diagram is complex enough.

The [theory page](http://www.graphviz.org/Theory.php) has some links that may be of interest.